# Error al crear un botón de pagos - MercadoPago

Tags: php, mercadopago, sdk

hace un tiempo implementé un botón de pago de MercadoPago en mi sitio y funcionaba bien, de la nada misma empecé a recibir errores en el log y el btn no aparece, el error que recibo es:

```
2020/03/27 19:58:31 [error] 1286#1286: *3520 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Wrong type NULL. It should be integer for property sponsor_id in /var/www/html/lib/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entity.php:459
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/lib/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entity.php(368): MercadoPago\Entity->tryFormat(NULL, 'integer', 'sponsor_id')
    #1 /var/www/html/lib/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entity.php(483): MercadoPago\Entity->_setValue('sponsor_id', NULL, false)
    #2 /var/www/html/lib/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Entity.php(259): MercadoPago\Entity->_fillFromArray(Object(MercadoPago\Preference), Array)
```

Este es mi código

```
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                         // Crea un objeto de preferencia
                      $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
                      // Crea un ítem en la preferencia
                      $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
                      $item->title = 'Plan Test';
                      $item->unit_price = 1;
                      $item->quantity =1;
                      $item->binary_mode = "true";

                      $preference->items = array($item);
                      $preference->save();
```

Si elimino "$item->quantity=1" me imprime el botón, pero logicamente en el log me aparece el error de que tengo que indicar la cantidad de artículos.

Estuve revisando y no pude encontrar porque se comenzo a dar este error.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo desde hace unas horas, antes funcionaba bien. Creo que se trata de un error temporal de la API con la que está integrada el SDK. Veremos que pasa mañana. Cualquier novedad avisar por favor.

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo a mí, tenía mi web funcionando bien con el botón de pago hace como un mes y ahora de la nada dejó de funcionar mi botón de pago, renové mis credenciales y nada. Estuve como 2 hora buscando el error en mi código pero se ve que no era eso. Espero que sea un error temporal.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba teniendo el mismo error: Wrong type NULL. It should be integer for property sponsor_id.

Actualice el SDK con composer y las primeras veces me siguio tirando el mismo error, hice un update por las dudas, borre toda la cache del sitio y ahora esta funcionando nuevamente.

Espero les sirva la respuesta.

Saludos!

Comment: No se quien no marco que esta no es la respuesta, acabo de recibir la respuesta de mercado y pago y esta es EXACTAMENTE la respuesta:

Te comentamos que presentamos inconvenientes con nuestra SDK que devuelve este error. En base a esto hemos lanzado una nueva versión de la misma (1.8.1). Podrías actualizar la misma? De este modo solucionarás este inconveniente. 

¡Saludos!

 El equipo de soporte a desarrolladores de Mercado Pago.

Developer Experience 

Mercado Libre | Mercado Pago

Comment: Actualizar el SDK con composer, solucionó este problema, gracias.